# Transforming embeded JSON string to a proper JSON object

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am using an XSLT mediator to transform an XML payload into a JSON payload, but the resulting JSON output is not as expected since the whole JSON is wrapped as a field value. Also, I just need to use this XSLT mediator, not any others. Here is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:ns="http://service.com">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
{
    "response": {
        "animals": {
            "animal": [
                <xsl:for-each select="//ns:animal">
                {
                    "name": "<xsl:value-of select="ns:name"/>",
                    "color": "<xsl:value-of select="ns:color"/>",
                    "info": {
                        "animalInfo": [
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns:info/ns:animalInfo">
                            {
                                "someVal1": "<xsl:value-of select="ns:someVal1"/>",
                                "someVal2": "<xsl:value-of select="ns:someVal2"/>"
                            }<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        ]
                    }
                }<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            ]
        }
    }
}
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the resulting JSON output as a string inside a "text" field. The whole JSON is wrapped as a `text` field value:

NOTE: When it's wrapped there are escape characters `\`. I removed them to make the JSON clear.

```
{
   "text": "{
      "response":{
         "animals":{
            "animal":[
               {
                  "name": "name",
                  "color": "color",
                  "info":{
                     "animalInfo":[
                        {
                           "someVal1":"someVal1",
                           "someVal2":"someVal2"
                        },
                        {
                           "someVal1":"someVal3",
                           "someVal2":"someVal4"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "name": "name",
                  "color": "color",
                  "info":{
                     "animalInfo":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }"
}
```

The JSON response I need after removing the `text` field and unwrapping its value,

```
  {
    "response":{
             "animals":{
                "animal":[
                   {
                      "name": "name",
                      "color": "color",
                      "info":{
                         "animalInfo":[
                            {
                               "someVal1":"someVal1",
                               "someVal2":"someVal2"
                            },
                            {
                               "someVal1":"someVal3",
                               "someVal2":"someVal4"
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "name": "name",
                      "color": "color",
                      "info":{
                         "animalInfo":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

**Unedited JSON Payload.**

```json
{
   "text": "{\"response\":{\"animals\":{\"animal\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"color\":\"color\",\"info\":{\"animalInfo\":[{\"someVal1\":\"someVal1\",\"someVal2\":\"someVal2\"},{\"someVal1\":\"someVal3\",\"someVal2\":\"someVal4\"}]}},{\"name\":\"name\",\"color\":\"color\",\"info\":{\"animalInfo\":[]}}]}}}"
}
```

I tried so hard to unwrap the JSON from this text field but I am unable to resolve it and even not sure why this is keep happening. Can someone please help me to resolve this using XSLT? Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT is for working with XMLs and not the other way around. Why can't you use any other mediators here? Also, add the Input XML format and the expected output JSON format.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what your required output is, or how the actual output differs. Your code seems to be producing exactly the output one would expect.

Comment: Your XSLT produces a JSON object containing a single key (`response`) but in your output that response is embedded in _another_ JSON object, which I have to assume is generated by the environment in which your XSLT is running (i.e. `wso2-micro-integrator`). The XSLT itself looks OK, though NB you would need to escape " and \ characters if you have to copy them from your input XML

Comment: @ycr @MichaelKay @Conal Tuohy I have updated my question. I made a mistake while adding the output JSON since I formatted it to make it clear. Actually, the issue is the whole JSON I need is inside that `text` field as its value. I need to remove that field `text` and unwrap that JSON value as the complete JSON. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm still not understanding your issue. Are you getting an embedded JSON within a JSON as a string? Do you want to convert that to a proper JSON?

Comment: The issue is not with your XSLT. Your XSLT is OK (though NB it probably should handle \ and " characters). The real problem is in the environment in which your XSLT is running. That environment is launching the XSLT and capturing its output and sticking it into a JSON document. Unfortunately I know nothing about `wso2` so I can't help you there.

Comment: @ycr Yes exactly. The actual JSON I need is coming inside a JSON body but as the `text` field value. For ex: `{ "text": "Actual JSON is here. Wrapped as a value"}`. I need to unwrap it and also remove that `text` also.

Comment: @ConalTuohy Oh ok I get it. That's fine. Thank you for the comments. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the P`ayloadfactory Mediator` or the `Script Mediator` here. Take a look at the following code.

**Payload Factory Mediator**

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
       <format>$1</format>
       <args>
         <arg expression="json-eval($.text)" evaluator="json"/>
       </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

**Script Mediator**

```xml
<property expression="json-eval($.text)" name="jsonText" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<script language="nashornJs"><![CDATA[
    var pl = JSON.parse(mc.getProperty('jsonText'));
    mc.setPayloadJSON(pl);
]]></script>
```